# What is the unique identifier in BigQuery GA4 events data?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics, google-analytics-4

Is there a column or combination of columns within BigQuery GA4 events data that uniquely identifies a record?  I'm asking because the `event_params`, `user_properties` and `items` fields contain nested json and when parsing them, I'm trying to ensure the related records are kept together.

***Hello Minhaz, Thanks for your help!

I've appended a picture to the description below which shows the output when checking for multiple rows using those 4 columns you mentioned.

**Notice how, for those event_name, event_timestamp, user_pseudo_id, event_bundle_sequence_id values, there are multiple rows with differing event_parms values?**

**Should we be combining the event_parms data from the multiple rows into one? I guess we were expecting all related event_parms values to display within one vent_name, event_timestamp, user_pseudo_id, event_bundle_sequence_id record, if that makes sense?**

[image]

```
select d.cnt,
  g.event_date
, g.event_timestamp
, g.event_name
, g.event_previous_timestamp
, g.event_value_in_usd
, g.event_bundle_sequence_id
, g.event_server_timestamp_offset
, g.user_id
, g.user_pseudo_id
, g.user_first_touch_timestamp
, g.event_params
from dbo.GA4Events g
    inner join (
                select 
                  event_date
                , event_timestamp
                , event_name
                , event_previous_timestamp
                , event_value_in_usd
                , event_bundle_sequence_id
                , event_server_timestamp_offset
                , user_id
                , user_pseudo_id
                , user_first_touch_timestamp
                , count(*) as cnt
                from dbo.GA4Events
                group by 
                  event_date
                , event_timestamp
                , event_name
                , event_previous_timestamp
                , event_value_in_usd
                , event_bundle_sequence_id
                , event_server_timestamp_offset
                , user_id
                , user_pseudo_id
                , user_first_touch_timestamp
                having count(*) > 1) d on 
                isnull(g.event_date,'')                              = isnull(d.event_date,'')
                and isnull(g.event_timestamp,'')                     = isnull(d.event_timestamp,'')
                and isnull(g.event_name ,'')                         = isnull(d.event_name,'')
                and isnull(g.event_previous_timestamp,'')            = isnull(d.event_previous_timestamp,'')
                and isnull(g.event_value_in_usd,'')                  = isnull(d.event_value_in_usd,'')
                and isnull(g.event_bundle_sequence_id,'')            = isnull(d.event_bundle_sequence_id,'')
                and isnull(g.event_server_timestamp_offset,'')       = isnull(d.event_server_timestamp_offset,'')
                and isnull(g.user_id,'')                             = isnull(d.user_id,'')
                and isnull(g.user_pseudo_id,'')                      = isnull(d.user_pseudo_id,'')
                and isnull(g.user_first_touch_timestamp,'')          = isnull(d.user_first_touch_timestamp,'')
order by 
  g.event_date
, g.event_timestamp
, g.event_name
, g.event_previous_timestamp
, g.event_value_in_usd
, g.event_bundle_sequence_id
, g.event_server_timestamp_offset
, g.user_id
, g.user_pseudo_id
, g.user_first_touch_timestamp
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Would you try below ?  [Documentation](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7029846) says,

###### User

> The user fields contain information that uniquely identifies the user associated with the event.

| Field name | Data type | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| user_id | STRING | The user ID set via the setUserId API. |
| user_pseudo_id | STRING | The pseudonymous id (e.g., app instance ID) for the user. |
| user_first_touch_timestamp | INTEGER | The time (in microseconds) at which the user first opened the app or visited the site. |

###### Event

> The event fields contain information that uniquely identifies an event.

| Field name | Data type | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| event_date | STRING | The date when the event was logged (YYYYMMDD format in the registered timezone of your app). |
| event_timestamp | INTEGER | The time (in microseconds, UTC) when the event was logged on the client. |
| event_previous_timestamp | INTEGER | The time (in microseconds, UTC) when the event was previously logged on the client. |
| event_name | STRING | The name of the event. |
| event_value_in_usd | FLOAT | The currency-converted value (in USD) of the event's "value" parameter. |
| event_bundle_sequence_id | INTEGER | The sequential ID of the bundle in which these events were uploaded. |
| event_server_timestamp_offset | INTEGER | Timestamp offset between collection time and upload time in micros. |

Comment: Hi Jaytiger,

Thanks for that link, I was hoping that combination would uniquely identify a record, but based on query results, it doesn't.  For the combination of event_date, event_timestamp, event_name, event_previous_timestamp, event_value_in_usd
, event_bundle_sequence_id, event_server_timestamp_offset we are seeing 100,000s of records that have dupes.

Comment: @MatthewWalk, I'm just curious that (`user`, `event`) combination will make uniqueness. Sorry but would you try it again with additional `User` fields ?  (This isn't reproducible with the GA4 data I have)

Comment: Hi @JayTiger,

Thanks again for your help!
I've edited the description above, adding the updated query including both the event and user fields to show the dupes (seeing around 90K dupes for one day).

Notice how, for those event and user values, there are multiple rows with differing event_parms values?

Should we be combining the event_parms data from the multiple rows into one? I guess we were expecting all related event_parms values to display within one vent_name, event_timestamp, user_pseudo_id, event_bundle_sequence_id record, if that makes sense?

Comment: The Problem is the batching multiple events may have the same timestamp for the same user.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: I found a problem and changed the partition to user_pseudo_id, event_timestamp,event_name and not session.

I use the following:

`farm_fingerprint(concat(user_pseudo_id,event_timestamp,event_name,row_number()over(partition by concat(user_pseudo_id, event_timestamp, event_name)))) as event_id`

To my knowledge, the events inside the GA4 dataset are already ordered by ingestion. So I generate some artificial event numbers for the events with row_number().

So far I did not find any duplicate event ids and results did not vary when executing.

Comment: Hey, not sure why you need event_name since I barely believe the same user will run more than an event in the same microsecond. Btw, here there is a discussion on this https://gist.github.com/markrittman/b64c6dc04e39886c8b7870f357e7300f#file-ga4_attribution-sql

Comment: This is because events are send in batches and if an event is send in the same batch it has the same timestamp. https://www.teamsimmer.com/2023/01/12/how-do-i-access-the-individual-timestamp-of-a-ga4-event/

Comment: Not working for me, it still seems the entire fingerprint can be NULL.

Comment: (due to user_pseudo_id being NULL)

Comment: @MariusSoutier try farm_fingerprint(concat(ifnull(user_pseudo_id,'anonymous'),event_timestamp,event_name,row_number()over(partition by concat(ifnull(user_pseudo_id,'anonymous'), event_timestamp, event_name)))) as event_id

Answer (score 1):

Edit: My initial answer below is wrong. It seems at present (Apr 2023), there isn't a sure shot way to identify unique records. A workaround could be taking the combination of the 4 fields mentioned below and adding that to a hash or fingerprint of the entire event_params object.

---

The combination of these four fields will be unique for each record in the GA4 BigQuery event export table: `event_name`, `event_timestamp`, `user_pseudo_id`, `event_bundle_sequence_id`.

Comment: Hello Minhaz,

I've appended some information to the description above, a question about the 4 fields you mentioned.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  :)

Comment: I updated my answer. Sorry I was wrong initially. There is a feature request on the roadmap to add an additional field which, in combination with the four fields I mentioned, would identify a unique record.

Comment: Thanks again @Minhaz Kazi!  That’s great to hear about that feature request.  Working with the existing state, would it make sense to UNION together event_params data from rows that repeat those 4 fields to create one record as opposed to the multiples we’ve been encountering?

Comment: Hi Minhaz,
Is there any update? Does one event could have multiple records?

Answer (score 1):

The only stable way to generate `event_id` that worked for me is to hash the whole table:

```
SELECT 
  FARM_FINGERPRINT(TO_JSON_STRING(t)) AS event_id,
  *
FROM  `project_id`.`dataset_id`.`events_YYYYMMDD` t
LIMIT 100;
```

---

**Note 1**

Use it only with exported tables (`events_YYYYMMDD`), not streaming ones (`events_intraday_YYYYMMDD`).
`event_id` will change for the same record because additional fields are added when data is migrated from events to events_intraday (more on this [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9358801)).

**Note 2**

Using `TO_JSON_STRING(t)` with a single table (`events_20240303`) vs a range of tables (`events_*`) can provide different results and unstable `event_id`. Thus preferable to use it with a single table only.
The reason is if in future tables a new field is added, `TO_JSON_STRING(t)` with table range will add this field with a null value for all the previous tables.

**Note 3**

From my understanding, GA4 export never changes already exported events — it might only add new events. Though I'm not certain about this, and if this is wrong (please let me know), the above approach is not stable either.

Comment: Thanks Klim!  That sounds like the safest option.  Isn’t it surprising that we’re left to figure this out on our own?

Comment: Hi @MatthewWalk! Oh yes, pretty surprising for such a fundamental feature. Hopefully, it will be added in the future.